# A cell appears when hovering on q-table row in quasar

Tags: hover, quasar-framework, quasar

There is a table on my application and the last column of it includes an icon button. I want the icon button for each row to appear only when I hover over the row. I'd like to know what the solution can be. I am using Quasar v1.

Here is my code regarding the table and the button:

```
<q-table
 bordered
 square
 flat
 class="my-sticky-column-table"
 :data="updatedSavedSearches"
 :columns="columns"
 row-key="title"
 :pagination.sync="pagination"
 @request="onRequest"
 @row-click="openSearch"
 >
  <template #body-cell-actions="props">
    <q-td :props="props">
     <q-btn flat icon="more_horiz" style="color: #717c8e" />
    </q-td>
 </template>
</q-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use simply css ?

```
<template>
<q-table>
  <template #body-cell-actions="props">
    <q-td :props="props" class="my-td">
     <q-btn class="my-button"/>
    </q-td>
 </template>
</q-table>
<template>
<style>
.my-button{
opacity: 0
}
td.my-td:hover .my-button{
opacity: 1
}
</style>
```